# WordPress: Contact Form 7 remove all classes and ids

Tags: php, wordpress

I started using WordPress plugin Contact Form 7 for backend solutions.

I already have a whole CSS code which gives to form my own style.

**So my question is:**

Is there any option how to remove all automatically added classes and ids? I need to have on my form only my classes with my own CSS styles.

**CLASSES AND IDS ALREADY ADDED:**

[image]

Comment: I think that really is a question for the plugin developer. It's very unlikely a plugin like this have that kind of option, but you'd have to check with them.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks